# High spike in incoming data, high CPU usage

Tags: iri-node

My incoming data to the node suddenly spiked from the usual 200 kbit/s to 11 Mbit/s. It has already tapered off, but I wonder what could have caused this.

It is IOTA traffic. It is one node which pushed that data to me. I think I was told that it is a swarm node, but I'm not certain about this. I have the IP and the DNS of the node which sent me that data, as well as the Slack contact for this node.

(I have the outgoing data limited to 1 Mbit/s in the INI file, that's the reason for the cutoff at the bottom, will change this this weekend)

Last couple of hours:
[image: last couple of hours]

Last 3 days:
[image: last 3 days]

CPU usage during that time (the graph is shifted as I created it later and readjusted it loosely):
[image]

I upgraded to 1.4.1.4 at around 8am so it was already running that version a couple of hours.

These are some graphs of the per-IP traffic from the machine that hosts the node

Incoming traffic

[image]

Outgoing traffic (The red block is DNS traffic)

[image]

Comment: Do you have any more precise logs? Is that traffic IOTA traffic?

Comment: @Helmar It is IOTA traffic. It is one node which pushed that data to me. I think I was told that it is a swarm node, but I'm not certain about this. I have the IP and the DNS of the node which sent me that data, as well as the Slack contact for this node.

Comment: did you already apply patch [#459](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/pull/459)?